# Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\CatalogComment::setUserId() must be an instance of App\Entity\User or null, int given

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to save my ID in my relation ManyToOne, but an error returned:

This is how i'm trying to save data:

```
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $catalogcomment = new CatalogComment();
    $form = $this->createForm(CatalogCommentType::class, $catalogcomment);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $catalogcomment->setUserId($user);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($catalogcomment);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('catalog_index');
    }
```

And this is my Entity CatalogComment related with the relation user_id

```
public function getUserId(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function setUserId(?User $user_id): self
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;

        return $this;
    }
```

The error received is:

Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\CatalogComment::setUserId() must be an instance of App\Entity\User or null, int given

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Doctrine ORM can be a bit tricky to get used to especially when folks come from a more "sqlish" background.  In most cases, you deal with objects and not object id's.  So use: $user = $this->getUser();  And change your CatalogComment stuff to get/setUser instead of userId.  Better yet, work thought some of the examples in the docs just to get an idea of how things work.

Comment: You are right, just changed $user = $this->getUser()->getUsername(); for $user = $this->getUser(); and it works like a charm. xD

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Consider accepting the answer below as the person did take the time to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to adjust your mapped relationship in the Entity CatalogComment not to have a property $userId but instead a property $user which should be of type User

```
class CatalogComment
{
     // ...

     /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
}
```

You have to create getter and setter for $user too, and then you can set the user in an CatalogComment Object as follows

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$catalogComment = new CatalogComment();
$catalogComment->setUser($user);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($catalogComment);
$em->flush();
```

Hope it helps :)